# Centering XSLT, CSS & XSLT (Second set of eyes)

Tags: css, xslt

Was hoping I could get a second set of eyes on this, I am stumped.

This XSL is producing three issues I cannot figure out.
1. On Google Chrome, it displays in the center of the browser as expected.  In IE 8, (We are still using this), the whole thing displays left aligned.
2. The Adobe.gif image link used to display in the center of the , and now it is left aligned.
3. The page container looks to run down past where it does using the same settings on other pages, (html/css).

It seems like I am missing a closing tag somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.  The only thing I can think of is that the css is not working properly?

I am not sure if I recall seeing that css will not work in xslt?  I have worked on the adobe.gif problem, I tried a style="" tag, and a  tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/dataroot">
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Intranet</title>
      <script type="text/javascript"  src="../../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/tacamo.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="page-container" style="margin: auto">
         <div id="header-container">
            <img src="../images/elements/header.png" alt="" width="1000" align="middle"/>
         </div> <!-- /Header Container-->
         <div id="nav-container">
            <div id="menu">
               <script>
                  $(document).ready(function()
                     {$("#menu").load("../includes/instructions-menu.txt");}
                  );
               </script>
            </div> <!-- /Menu Container-->
         </div> <!-- /Navigation Container -->
         <div id="instructions-content-container">
         <table class="instructions" align="center">
         <tr>
            <th style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">Instruction Number</th>
            <th style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">Date</th>
            <th style="width: 25px; text-align: center;">COG</th>
            <th style="width: 500px">Description</th>
            <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;">Open</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="tblInstructions">
         <xsl:sort select="i_num"/>
         <tr>
         <xsl:attribute name="style">
         <!-- Sets Even Rows Blue -->
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
            background-color: #C0D0E0;
         </xsl:if>
         <!-- Sets Odd Rows White -->
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
         </xsl:if>
         </xsl:attribute>
            <td style="width: 75px"><xsl:value-of select="i_num"/></td>
<!-- XSLT 1.0 / XPATH String Function Hack Job to get the Dates to drop ISO 8601 format -->
<!-- Future - Update Hackjob to display in military format DDMMMYY 01JAN14 -->
            <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center;">
        <xsl:variable name="dt" select="i_date"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                      substring($dt, 6, 2),
                      '/',
                      substring($dt, 9, 2),
                      '/',
                      substring($dt, 1, 4)
                      )"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25px; text-align: center;"><xsl:value-of select="i_cog"/></td>
            <td style="width: 500px"><xsl:value-of select="i_desc"/></td>
            <td style="width: 25px"><a href="{i_loc}" target="_blank"><img src="../images/elements/pdf-logo.gif" height="25" width="25" border="0" /></a></td>
         </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
         </div> <!-- /Instructions Content Container -->
         <div id="footer-container">
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function()
                  {$("#footer-container").load("../includes/admin-footer.txt");}
               );
            </script>
         </div> <!-- /Footer Container -->

      </div> <!-- /Page Container -->
   </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put IE into standards compliant mode by replacing

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"/>
```

Comment: Martin, that was brilliant, thank you!  That centered everything and cleaned up the div run off at the bottom.  I wish I could upvote your solution...